# Posts otimizados no Facebook Mobile

Tags: mobile, facebook

Alguém sabe como fazer esses novos posts otimizados para Facebook Mobile?

Exemplo:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome é Instant Articles

https://instantarticles.fb.com/

Existe até plugin do wordpress que já faz isso pra você.